# Show all divs with data attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, custom-data-attribute

I want to show and hide divs based on the selected data-attribute with bootstrap tabs. How can I do this?.

I have tried lots of solutions but nothing really works.

Comment: Dont need bootstrap. use simple Jquery or even javscript will do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/3regqgas/

Comment: Please add any relevant code to your question.

Comment: I am looking for somting that dooes almost the asame as this page.... http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices